# How to use calculated div width to set text width in React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, jsx

So I have just converted my standard website into a react app and am struggling with a style component that is effectively a split color text element that is controlled by the container div width. See code pen [here](https://codepen.io/drucial/pen/poworrV) for the split text effect on multiple divs / text elements on a page.

I initially thought I could just copy the function into react component(changing class names) but it acts very strangely. When simply pasted in, it renders just fine, but on page refresh or navigation, it throws flags and won't render because the div elements don't exist?? or more specifically 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null'. If I comment out the setTextSplit function and refresh the page, it renders without the text split, and then I can un-comment the function and it displays correctly on all posts on the page. refresh or navigate to another page and it crashes.

React Component Below:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState} from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import sanityClient from "../client";

export default function Home() {
  const [allPostsData, setAllPosts] = useState(null);

  function setTextSplit() {
    let sideWidth = document.querySelector('.hero-description').offsetWidth;
    let before = document.querySelectorAll(".before");
    for(let i = 0; i < before.length; i++) {
    before[i].style.width = before[i].offsetWidth - sideWidth + 16 + 'px';
    }
  }
  setTextSplit()

  useEffect(() => {
    sanityClient
      .fetch(
        `*[_type == "post"]{
        title,
        postNumber,
        excerpt,
        slug,
        publishedOn,
        imageAlt,
        mainImage{
          asset->{
          _id,
          url
        }
      }
    }`
      )
      .then((data) => setAllPosts(data))
      .catch(console.error);
  }, []);
  return (
      <main>
        {allPostsData &&
          allPostsData.map((post, index) => (
            <section key={index} className='hero-post'>
                <Link to={"/" + post.slug.current} key={post.slug.current} className="hero-image-link" >
                    <img className='hero-image' src={post.mainImage.asset.url} alt={post.imageAlt} />
                </Link>
                <div className='hero-description'>
                    <p className='hero-post-date'>{post.publishedOn}</p>
                    <p>{post.excerpt}</p>
                    <Link to={"/" + post.slug.current} key={post.slug.current} className='hero-post-link'>
                        <p>Keep Reading >></p>
                    </Link>
                    <div className="text-container">
                        <h1 className='hero-title'>{post.title}<span className='hero-post-number'>/{post.postNumber}</span></h1>
                        <h1 className='hero-title before'>{post.title}<span className='hero-post-number'>/{post.postNumber}</span></h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </section>
          ))}
      </main>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always try to prevent `document.querySelector` calls in React Components. Especially when targeting elements that are being rendered by the same component.

The issue is that there is no guarantee that the element exists. It might exist in some scenarios and work, but it is not reliable.

Try using [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) to create a reference to the HTML element. Then delay the function using a [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) hook so that it only runs when the `allPostsData` variable is changed.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import sanityClient from '../client';

export default function Home() {
  const [allPostsData, setAllPosts] = useState(null);
  const mainRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!mainRef.current) return;
    
    let descriptions = mainRef.current.querySelectorAll('.hero-description');
    
    for (let i = 0; i < descriptions.length; i++) {
      const before = descriptions[i].querySelector('.before');
      before.style.width = before.offsetWidth - descriptions[i].offsetWidth + 16 + 'px';
    }    
  }, [allPostsData]);

  useEffect(() => {
    sanityClient
      .fetch(
        `*[_type == "post"]{
        title,
        postNumber,
        excerpt,
        slug,
        publishedOn,
        imageAlt,
        mainImage{
          asset->{
          _id,
          url
        }
      }
    }`
      )
      .then((data) => setAllPosts(data))
      .catch(console.error);
  }, []);
  return (
    <main ref={mainRef}>
      {allPostsData &&
      allPostsData.map((post, index) => (
        <section key={index} className="hero-post">
          <Link to={'/' + post.slug.current} key={post.slug.current} className="hero-image-link">
            <img className="hero-image" src={post.mainImage.asset.url} alt={post.imageAlt} />
          </Link>
          <div className="hero-description">
            <p className="hero-post-date">{post.publishedOn}</p>
            <p>{post.excerpt}</p>
            <Link to={'/' + post.slug.current} key={post.slug.current} className="hero-post-link">
              <p>Keep Reading >></p>
            </Link>
            <div className="text-container">
              <h1 className="hero-title">{post.title}<span className="hero-post-number">/{post.postNumber}</span></h1>
              <h1 className="hero-title before">{post.title}<span className="hero-post-number">/{post.postNumber}</span>
              </h1>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
      ))}
    </main>
  );
}
```

Here are code examples to run the `useEffect` also on window resize events.

### 1. Add event listener in `useEffect`:

The easiest solution is to wrap the logic in a function like you originally had and register a resize event listener in the callback.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    function update() {
      if (!mainRef.current) return;

      let descriptions = mainRef.current.querySelectorAll('.hero-description');

      for (let i = 0; i < descriptions.length; i++) {
        const before = descriptions[i].querySelector('.before');
        before.style.width = before.offsetWidth - descriptions[i].offsetWidth + 16 + 'px';
      }
    }
    
    // call the update function initially
    update();
    
    // register resize listener
    window.addEventListener('resize', update);
    
    // cleanup resize listener after unmount or dependency update
    return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', update);
  }, [allPostsData]);
```

### 2. Add custom hook:

The second solution involves creating a custom hook that tells you the window size. You can then add this hook into your component and pass the `size` variable to the `useEffect` dependencies.

An example hook is:

```
export function useWidth() {
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(window.innerWidth);

  useEffect(() => {
    function handleResize() {
      setWidth(window.innerWidth);
    }
    
    window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);
    
    return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
  });

  return width;
}
```

Then in your component, make these changes:

```
  const width = useWidth();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!mainRef.current) return;

    let descriptions = mainRef.current.querySelectorAll('.hero-description');

    for (let i = 0; i < descriptions.length; i++) {
      const before = descriptions[i].querySelector('.before');
      before.style.width = before.offsetWidth - descriptions[i].offsetWidth + 16 + 'px';
    }
  }, [allPostsData, width]);
```

> Note: for both solutions, you probably want to [debounce](https://medium.com/@jamischarles/what-is-debouncing-2505c0648ff1) the window resize event.

Comment: That seems to be the consensus with what I read around using Google. unfortunately, I still have the same issue using your suggestion. I get the same type error.

Comment: I also get this error as well "Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function."

Comment: Oh, wait. I've updated the code since you are fetching the posts data. I've added the `allPostsData` variable to the dependencies array of the `useEffect` so that it will run when the data is loaded. I've also changed the selector order so that it also works when no elements are found. The error that you are seeing is probably caused by the fetch call being resolved while the component is unmounted.

Comment: This is working beautifully! So just to make sure I understand for future reference, the reason the first solution didn't work is because the useEffect hook for the text split wasn't dependent on the allPostsData variable rendering? if I wanted that useEffect to run also on window resize, any suggestions there? can I just add an event listener to the dependencies?

Comment: Exactly, the `useEffect` callback only runs once. Since you are working with async data, you want the callback to be executed each time the data is changed. There are multiple ways to also run the function on resize events. I will add them to the answer.

Comment: you are the GOAT man. Its funny, I actually came up with essentially the exact same code from option 1 and ran into an issue where it does not correctly set the offset width. It does initially on the first render but on resize render it is way off.